# How to Type a Component Prop for Accepting CSS Classes in React

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

Trying to accept classNames in a component as a different prop than `className` but found that this is not working in IDE (tested on VS Code & PhpStorm). All TS class suggestions are gone.
Following are my implementations

```js
type MyComponentProps = {
  additionalClasses?: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>['className'];
};

const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {
    // ...
}
```

When using this in another component

```js
<MyComponent 
    additionalClasses="" // no suggestion here :(
/>
```

How do I type this?